# insert the link of the file uploaded to google drive into database?

Tags: google-drive-api

I am going to upload my web files of images to my google drive account for flexible reason (so that I don't worry to backup it as I do it from my vps service and the space is yummy too).

The file I am going to upload to google drive will be emebeded into my website automatically.

So my question is, can I get the permanent link as I upload it to google drive and insert the link into my database.

for example if I upload 10 pictures to google drive with the api, and as I upload it, google drive send back the link that I will insert into database

```
  +-----+---------------+-------------------------------+
  | id  |   file_name   |        url_from_google        |
  +-----+---------------+-------------------------------+
  |  1  |   one.jpg     |  gooledrive/userkey/one.jpg   |   
  |  2  |   two.jpg     |  gooledrive/userkey/two.jpg   |   
  |  3  |   three.jpg   |  gooledrive/userkey/three.jpg |   
  |  4  |   four.jpg    |  gooledrive/userkey/four.jpg  |   
  |  5  |   five.jpg    |  gooledrive/userkey/five.jpg  |   
  |  6  |   six.jpg     |  gooledrive/userkey/six.jpg   |   
  |  7  |   seven.jpg   |  gooledrive/userkey/seven.jpg |   
  |  8  |   eight.jpg   |  gooledrive/userkey/eight.jpg |   
  |  9  |   nine.jpg    |  gooledrive/userkey/nine.jpg  |   
  |  9  |   ten.jpg     |  gooledrive/userkey/ten.jpg   |  
  +-----+---------------+-------------------------------+
```

By that I can easily loop the ten images into my website by echoing the `url_from_google` in the `src` of `<img>` tag.

How to do this if it is possible? Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. The response to your insert request will be a file resource (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files). You want the webContentLink, presuming that you've made the files public.